# Как получить адрес? 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lpBaseOfDll'

Tags: python, pymem

При попытке запустить код вылезает ошибка: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lpBaseOfDll'. Нашёл тему, в которой решалась эта проблема, но мне не помогло.

```
import pymem
import pymem.process

dwEntityList = (0x4DA21AC)
dwGlowObjectManager = (0x52EA640)
m_iGlowIndex = (0xA438)
m_iTeamNum = (0xF4)


def main():
    pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")

    module = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client_panorama.dll")
    client = module.lpBaseOfDll

    while True:

        glow_manager = pm.read_int(client + dwGlowObjectManager)

        for i in range(1, 32):

            entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10)

            if entity:

                entity_team_id = pm.read_int(entity + m_iTeamNum)
                entity_glow = pm.read_int(entity + m_iGlowIndex)

                if entity_team_id == 2: # Terrorist
                    pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x4, float(1))
                    pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x8, float(0))
                    pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0xC, float(0))
                    pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x10, float(1))
                    pm.write_int(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x24, 1)
                elif entity_team_id == 3: # Counter-terrorist
                    pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x4, float(0))
                    pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x8, float(0))
                    pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0xC, float(1))
                    pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x10, float(1))
                    pm.write_int(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x24, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: напишите полный текст ошибки в вопросе

Comment: В `module` получается `None`, не находит процесс видимо